# How do you generically convert values of variant types to strings?

Tags: reason

Say I have a sum type consisting of the following data constructors...

```ml
type Entity =
 | Student 
 | Staff
 | Classes
```

Is there a way of polymorphically converting values from a given sum type into values of type string which does not resort to the below.

```ml
let showEntity = e =>
 switch (e){
 | Student   => "Student" 
 | Staff     => "Staff"
 | Classes   => "Classes"
```

Comment: Short of using some sort of code generation tool, there's not.

Comment: As ivg answers below, this is done with PPX–just for context, in OCaml there is a family of well-known 'deriving' PPXs which automate the boilerplate of writing out various type-driven conversions like 'derive to string', 'derive to JSON', 'derive ordering/equality', etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is done using ppx preprocessing in OCaml/Reason, for example, using the ppx_deriving library<sup>1</sup>,

```
[@deriving show({with_path: false})]
type t = Hello | World;

let main () =
  print_endline("Hello, " ++ show(World));

main ();
```

and running it with `dune exec ./main.exe` shows us our beloved

```
dune exec ./main.exe
Hello, World
```

provided that the code is in the `main.re` file, and there is a file named `dune` in the same folder with the following content

```
(executable
 (name main)
 (preprocess (pps ppx_deriving.std)))
```

and that the `ppx_deriving` library and `dune` are installed, assuming that you're using opam. If you're using bucklescript, then install the [bs-deriving](https://libraries.io/npm/bs-deriving) package. In fact, there are plenty of libraries that provide derivers, as well as different derivers, so it is hard to suggest one (and suggesting a library would be out of the scope for SO, so consider this as a general demonstration).

---

<sup>1)</sup>
Note also, that the `show` deriver takes a parameter `{with_path: false)`, if we will use the deriver without parameters, e.g.,

```
 [@deriving show]
 type t = Hello | World;
```

it will show names prefixed with a module name, which is probably not what you want.